# Group by Object ID's in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of ID's and organizations like so:

```
var ids = ['1','2', '3'];
var orgs =
    [ 
      { name: "Org 1", id: 1 },
      { name: "Org 2", id: 2 },
      { name: "Org 3", id: 2 }
    ]
```

I want to loop through these to output something like this:

```
{
    1: [
        {name: "Org 1", id: 1}
    ],
    2: [
        {name: "Org 2", id: 2},
        {name: "Org 3", id: 2}
    ]
}
```

I tried this without success:

```
var results = orgs.forEach(function (org) {
    if (results[org.id]) {
        results.push(org)
    } else {
        results[org.id] = [org]
    };
});
```

Comment: Your `results` is an *invalid* structure.  `{ [ ] }` is invalid, you can't have an object without keys.

Comment: Thanks @RocketHazmat - I think i've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to use a library like Underscore, Ramda, or Lo-Dash, then it's simple enough to write this using `reduce`:

```
var results = orgs.reduce(function(results, org) {
    (results[org.id] = results[org.id] || []).push(org);
    return results;
}, {})
```

Comment: Thanks Scott - exactly what I'm searching for.

Comment: But notice that libraries also make this easy.  With [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) you could just do `R.groupBy(R.prop('id'), orgs);`.  And if you wanted a reusable function, it would just be `var groupById = R.groupBy(R.prop('id'));`.  Lo-Dash and Underscore offer fairly similar functionality.

Comment: Slightly newer syntax

`var results = orgs.reduce((results, org) => ({...results, [org.id]: org}), {})`

Comment: @Headless: that will only allow one entry per key.  The question requests an array of them, and in fact, `"2"` will have two entries in the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) and just return your id

http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

```
_.groupBy([1.3, 2.1, 2.4], function(num){ return Math.floor(num); });
// => {1: [1.3], 2: [2.1, 2.4]}
```

you might also want to take a look at [lo-dash](https://lodash.com/)